# Show Scrollbar of component A in Component B

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components like this.

```
<ComponentA />
<ComponentB />
```

Where component A will be horizontally scrollable but i want to show its scrollbar in component B.

```
<ComponentA >
some content over here which is wide enough to get horizontal scroll
</ComponentA>

<ComponentB>
some content
//scrollbar of ComponentA
more content
</ComponentB>
```

Hope i made the problem clear :)

I guess i can use useRef but don't know how in this scenario

Comment: I don't understand your question... What do you mean by the scrollbar of component A?

Comment: You can only have working scrollbars on element that have wider/taller content than the parent.

So either you have to make content of componentB wider then B, or maybe put ComponentA inside ComponentB?

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie i hope i understand your question and i try my best.
use `overflow-x/overflow-y: scroll;`
so you can easily get a scrollbar in component A, but this will always visible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).